# Can I access office.js from SharePoint 2013 content-editor web-part like I can Ewa?

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2013, excel-addins, office365-apps, office-js

I have HTML and JavaScript that run just fine in a SharePoint 2013 content-editor web-part, from which I can access the Ewa.EwaControl object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee589018.aspx) to get to the various Excel Web Parts hosted on the page.

The Ewa has some limitations that I'd like to overcome by using the office.js (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx).

Also, both Ewa and office.js seem to do a similar thing, but I can't find anything on the internet that indicates which is deprecated in favor of which.  With SharePoint 2016 requiring Office Online Server, and Excel Web Parts now being subsumed by Office Online Server, what does that mean with regard to the future of either office.js or Ewa?  They seem to have overlapping features and it's unclear which we should invest in.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all teams but I work on Office.js and I can assure you at least we are actively working on Office.js. We are bringing in tons of New APIs with Office 2016 and try to reach as many platforms as we can. You can find all the released APIs and ongoing effort from out Documentation on Github. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs
 I hope that helps you make your decision.

Thanks,
Sky

Comment: We're a Microsoft shop and would love nothing more than to follow your recommendations.   Offise.js looks great, but unfortunately we cannot use it.   Office.js is only for Office Add-ins.   Excel Add-ins don't work when embedded in a SharePoint page with the Excel Web Access.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321053/how-to-published-an-office-add-in-to-sharepoint-for-use-with-excel-web-app  Also, Office Task-Panes display by default, which we don't wan't.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321407/how-can-office-add-in-task-pane-not-display-by-default.

Comment: Microsoft road-map for Excel, other than the desktop edition, has been unclear for a decade. Excel Services, Excel Web Access, Office Online, with different APIs out but not in parity. Published back-end APIs are not used by client-side APIs but a different, undocumented, back-end API are used with  more capabilities. I can't even get the unminified version of the Ewa.js files from MS so I can fix the problem myself: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621787/i-want-to-use-the-ewa-api-to-make-calls-into-methods-that-are-in-the-ewa-js-ew  #notveryopensource