# I want to use the Ewa API to make calls into methods that are in the Ewa.js / EwaMoss.js script files

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2013, office-js

The Ewa namespace is documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee589018.aspx

It's pretty easy to use, but certain calls are not documented and there's no sample code.   The source for Ewa.js is here:
https://s1-excel-15.cdn.office.net/x/sc/1662281009__layouts/App_Scripts/Ewa.js
But it's minimized.

If you look at the source, you will see that there's a call named "InsertDeleteCells".  If you put a breakpoint there, and then attempt to delete a row from the spreadsheet in edit mode, the breakpoint will hit.

Does anyone know how to make that call?  I'm assuming the starting point is the _Ewa and Ewa global objects, and that I would have to pass in the Session ID which I can get from the Ewa.EwaControl

Alternatively, if someone from Microsoft is willing to provide the non-minimized versions of Ewa.js and EwsMoss.js (probably called Ewa.debug.js and EwaMoss.debug.js), I can do the rest of the work.

Comment: Let me see if I can hunt down non-minimized versions of Ewa.js... I'll let you know if I do.

Comment: That would be amazing.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with the Excel team. The APIs called by Ewa.js are purely internal, so they may (and will) change over time. That is why they are not documented, and why there is not a non-minified version. While you may be able to hack something together that calls these APIs, such solution would be very fragile and susceptible to breaking, so it's not something we could, in good faith, recommend.  Essentially, only the "Ewa" namespace is public, while anything under "_Ewa" is intentionally private.

Hope this helps,

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: It does.   Unfortunately, this means I cannot delete a row from an Table.   In an insert a row to a Table by adding data to the row right under the Table.  Excel will than make that row part of the table.   But there's no way to delete a row from a table.   It's a shame that the full set of commands available to the EwaInternalWebService.json REST API has not been exposed to EWA.   I do appreciate ALL of your help, Michael

Comment: By the way, new APIs aren't being added to Ewa.   For instance, ExcelServices now has SaveWorkbook, etc., APIs that do not exist in Ewa, so I had to use Shahar Prish's very old ExcelServicesAjax.zip JavaScript wrapper.   That code only worked in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.  It won't even work in IE11, much less Chrome or FireFox.  I had to update that so that I can make ExcelServices call from JS.  Fortunately, the SessionIDs between it and Ewa Namespace are compatible.  I would have loved to just use officejs